# How do I incorporate a hidden/visible pannel in the best way?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a everyone-can-do interface and I intend to keep it as possible as I can. To do that I want to have an "exception" panel that will give the user the option to modify some more complex data fields.
My solution was to add a button "Exceptions" and the button sets the panel to visible --panel.setVisible(true)--, the problem is that the interface keeps it's original size, and when you press the "Exceptions", you also need to manually adjust the size of the window so that you can see that now the panel exists.

How can I make it so when the Exceptions panel hides or reveals, the window resizes automatically so that everything can be seen by the user?

Thank you!

Comment: Please mention what are you using. name of tools. languages etc

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using Swing, I know this can be tricky, if you only want to add the new panel dimension to the existing frame. 
Here is the toggle function I defined, and used to show/hide an explanation panel in a dialog frame:

```
    private void moreExplanationEvent(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getStateChange() == SELECTED) {
            Dimension dim = this.getSize();
            explanationPanel.setVisible(true);
            pack();
            dim.height = dim.height + explanationPanel.getHeight();
            this.setSize(dim);
            this.setPreferredSize(dim);
            pack();
        } else if (event.getStateChange() == DESELECTED) {
            Dimension dim = this.getSize();
            dim.height = dim.height - explanationPanel.getHeight();
            explanationPanel.setVisible(false);
            this.setSize(dim);
            this.setPreferredSize(dim);
            pack();
        }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, Is there a way that I can verify with "if" condition if the setVisibile state has changed?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you searching for the isVisible() method?